# How can I fix the Perfect match and Imperfect match functions?

Tags: c, function

For a school assignment, I have been tasked with making a simple codebreaker game using the functions and prototypes provided. You should be able to input the length and difficulty of the code, and type in numbers to make your guess. The part I'm having trouble with is determining the Perfect and Imperfect matches. The program needs to tell the player how many perfect matches (correct number in the correct place) their guess had, and then reveal the perfect matches. The latter I have correct, but the former is only returning with 56 perfect matches when I test it. And I don't really know where to start with the Imperfect matches section, and how I can get it to skip perfect matches. Is there any way I can do this without strings?

Keep in mind, this is a section of the code, not the entire program. It's in this section that things are breaking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>



void GetGuess(int guess[], int length) {
    int i;
    printf("\n\nPlease input your guesses.\n");
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        scanf("%d", &guess[i]);
    }
return;
}

void ProcessGuess(int hidelist[], int showlist[], int length, int guess[]) {
    int i;
    int perfectsum, imperfectsum;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(guess[i] == hidelist[i]){
            PerfectMatches(hidelist, guess, length);
            showlist[i] = guess[i];
        }
        else{
            ImperfectMatches(hidelist, guess, length);
        }
    }
    printf("You have %d perfect matches and %d imperfect matches!\n\n", perfectsum, imperfectsum);

return;
}

int PerfectMatches(int hidelist[], int guess[], int length) {
    int i;
    int perfectsum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(guess[i] == hidelist[i]){
            perfectsum++;
        }
    }
return perfectsum;
}

int ImperfectMatches(int hidelist[], int guess[], int length) {
    int i, j;
    int imperfectsum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < length; j++){
            if(i != j){
                if(hidelist[i] == guess[j]){
                    imperfectsum++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
return imperfectsum;
}

void copyArray(int dest[], int source[], int length) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in your function ProcessGuess you didn't get the return of the PerfectMatches and ImperfectMatches functions. So your perfectsum and imperfectsum aren't correct.

Then concerning the Imperfect Matches section you can use the PerfectMatches function but using != instead of == (if I understood the rules correctly)